# Trying to count() number of certain XML elements

Tags: xml, xslt, count

I have an XML file with thousands of prisons like this:

```
<bases xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<marker>
        <name>United States Penitentiary, Canaan</name>
        <adr>Canaan</adr>
        <state>Pennsylvania</state>
        <geo>41.562778, -75.421389</geo>
        <tag>Federal</tag>
        <wiki>United_States_Penitentiary,_Canaan</wiki>
</marker>
<marker>
        <name>Mohawk Correctional Facility</name>
        <adr>Rome</adr>
        <state>New York</state>
        <geo>43.184511, -75.483992</geo>
        <tag>State</tag>
        <wiki>Mohawk_Correctional_Facility</wiki>
</marker>
...
</bases>
```

I want to produce counts of the number of prisons whose <tag> is "Federal". I need to produce totals for eight  values. I'm using an XSLT v1.0 processor (xmlstarlet) and I'm new to count().

I have so many examples of XSL that haven't worked, I'm not sure which to include here. (I've been at this for hours.) Here's one that doesn't work:

```
<xsl:template match="/bases/marker[tag='Federal']">
        TOTAL = <xsl:value-of select="count(.)"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Help, please.

Here's the solution from Sebastien that solves the count() problem:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    TOTAL = <xsl:value-of select="count(//bases/marker[tag='Federal']) "/>
</xsl:template>
```

But I have multiple values of <tag> to process, and this doesn't work - States is equal to zero when there are hundreds:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
        Federal = <xsl:value-of select="count(//bases/marker[tag='Federal']) "/>
        State = <xsl:value-of select="count(//bases/marker[tag='Statel']) "/>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: I'm not sure how your templates are setup, but doing this should give you the count : count(//bases/marker[tag='Federal'])

Comment: Thanks for getting me on the right track.

Comment: For a single value doing `count(/bases/marker[tag='Federal'])` should be sufficient. If you want to do multiple counts for different values of `tag`, then consider *grouping* - see: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xslt-grouping/info.

Comment: I'm using a version 1 XSLT processor, so grouping looks like another learning curve :-)
I'm reading now.

Comment: Based on my reading, it appears that grouping is difficult or impossible with a version 1 XSLT processor. Is there another way?

Comment: https://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html

Comment: Grouping in 1.0 is more difficult than in 2.0+, but definitely not impossible. I've added an example as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example of Muenchian grouping in XSLT 1.0 to go along with the [link in the comments](https://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html).

**Input** (added another `marker` to show proper counting of `State`)

```xml
<bases xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <marker>
        <name>United States Penitentiary, Canaan</name>
        <adr>Canaan</adr>
        <state>Pennsylvania</state>
        <geo>41.562778, -75.421389</geo>
        <tag>Federal</tag>
        <wiki>United_States_Penitentiary,_Canaan</wiki>
    </marker>
    <marker>
        <name>Mohawk Correctional Facility</name>
        <adr>Rome</adr>
        <state>New York</state>
        <geo>43.184511, -75.483992</geo>
        <tag>State</tag>
        <wiki>Mohawk_Correctional_Facility</wiki>
    </marker>
    <marker>
        <name>Casa Bonita</name>
        <adr>Lakewood</adr>
        <state>CO</state>
        <geo>39.741927, -105.070828</geo>
        <tag>State</tag>
        <wiki>Casa_Bonita</wiki>
    </marker>
</bases>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    
    <xsl:key name="marker_by_tag" match="marker" use="tag"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <xsl:for-each select="marker[count(.|key('marker_by_tag',tag)[1])=1]">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(tag,' = ',count(key('marker_by_tag',tag)),'&#xA;')"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
Federal = 1
State = 2
```